# Stubbing/mocking intent in Android Espresso test

Tags: java, zxing, android-espresso, stubbing

I want to test the following flow in my application:

1. The user clicks on a scan button
2. onClick a ZXing app is launched
3. If a correct qr code is returned we proceed else user gets an option to enter the code manually

I want to test this flow using espresso. I think I have to use intended or intending [1](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/08/11/stub-your-android-intents/) but I an not sure how to check if the intent was ZXing and how to come back to the application.

Answer (score 3):

The general flow to using espresso-intents is this:

1. Call `intending(X).respondWith(Y)` in order to set up the mock.
2. Perform the action which should result in the intent being sent.
3. Call `intended(Z)` to verify that the mock received the expected intent.

X and Z could be identical, but I tend to make X as generalised as possible (e.g. only match the component name), and make Z be more specific (check values of extras, etc.).

e.g. For ZXing I might do something like this (warning: I haven't tested this code!):

```
Intents.intending(hasAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); // Match any ZXing scan intent
onView(withId(R.id.qr_scan_button).perform(click()); // I expect this to launch the ZXing QR scanner
Intents.intended(Matchers.allOf(
        hasAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"),
        hasExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"))); // Also matchs the specific extras I'm expecting
```

Comment: Not tested with ZXing but works in my example with ACTION_SEND